# dotCloud Docker vs traditional VM

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, containers

I am new to Docker.

What are the major differences between Docker and traditional VM?

Is Docker stable enough for daily use?

Comment: There are a few serious problems with this question - among them you don't define what a "traditional VM" is (VMware? VirtualBox? BSD Jails?), or what your criteria for "stability" are (though I suppose we can infer "doesn't crash" as a basic metric?) -- I think [the question Michael Hampton pointed you at](http://serverfault.com/q/294761/126632) might answer what you're looking for though. If so let me know and I'll mark this as a duplicate. If not, please make this question more specific and it may get reopened. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following appears on Docker's [Getting Started](http://www.docker.io/gettingstarted/) page:

> Docker is still under heavy development. It should not yet be used in production. Check the repo for recent progress.

That speaks volumes.

Its only being available for Ubuntu is also a serious problem...

Comment: Can anyone answer "the differences" part?

Comment: @linquize See [Explain in Plain English what is LXC and for what it is useful](http://serverfault.com/q/294761/126632), as well as the relevant web sites, Wikipedia, etc.